# Can I write to a database using Django models from async websocket client functions?

Tags: python, django, database, asynchronous, websocket

For a continuous high volume data stream some other party has set up a websocket endpoint for me (and only me) to connect to. I've got my current models in Django so I would like to connect from that. I found two Python websocket client libraries:

- https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client
- https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets

The first one (`websocket-client`) states that all functions are synchronous. Since the endpoint will have a continuous (fairly high volume) flow and I need to write the results to the (postgres) database, I would say I will need an async way of doing this. The second library called `websockets` has async ways of receiving stuff, but I'm unsure whether I can write to the DB using async functions. The reason I think that might be a problem is because in the Django Channels project [this page](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) has a note saying the following:

> any asynchronous consumer must be careful to avoid directly performing blocking operations, such as accessing a Django model.

So my questions are:

1. Can I write to the database using these async models?
2. If so, what are the things I should be carefull for?
3. Does anybody have any more tips on how to handle a large volume data stream over websockets?

Comment: Django-channels provides a way to write to db asynchronously. See this page: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/databases.html